# videos does not work in iOS 9.0.1

Tags: ios, video

My code was working fine on ios8, while it does not work on ios 9. It actually does not work for other videos, for videos in photo library, it works well. Please help!

It is an video play app, the main code is as below:

```
AVURLAsset *movieAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:wpTrack.url options:nil];
    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:movieAsset];
    _audioPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
    AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:_audioPlayer];
    playerLayer.frame = _playerView.layer.bounds;
    playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect;


for (CALayer *layer in [_playerView.layer sublayers]) {
    if ([layer isKindOfClass:[AVPlayerLayer class]]) {
        [layer removeFromSuperlayer];
    }
}
[_playerView.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];
[_audioPlayer setAllowsExternalPlayback:YES];
[playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like iOS9 added some network security checking stuff, the issue fixed after I added below code into Info.plist.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```